# Azure Data Studio on Mac issue with Slow Query (qds) Widget on Dashboard

Tags: sql-server, macos, azure, sql-server-2017, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to follow the procedures here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/tutorial-qds-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 to add the 5 slowest queries to the database dashboard, everything is going fine, but somehow the system is concatenating twice the folder path and therefore showing me this error:

> Could not find query file at any of the following paths :
>    /Applications/Azure Data Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/insights-default/Applications/Azure Data Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/insights-default/sql/qds_detail.sql

I searched in what's supposed to be the "right" directory */Applications/Azure Data Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/insights-default/sql/qds_detail.sql* and I can see both the qds.sql and qds_details.sql but because of this wrong path concatenating, Azure Data Studio cannot find the file.

I'm pretty new using this and I wonder if there's some other setting (or JSON) I can change to make the app to point the right directory.

As additional information, please note that I have SQL Server 2017 and it's running in a Docker Container in the same machine running the Azure Data Studio (because there's no MSSQL Server for Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old but try saving the script in local folder. Worked for me.
Ended up looking like:

```
"queryFile": "C:/SQL2019/activeSession.sql",
                            "details": {
                                "queryFile": "C:/SQL2019/activeSessionDetail.sql",
                                "label": "SID",
                                "value": "Login Name"
                            }
```